# how to change where automake installs a libtool library?

Tags: hdf5, automake, libtool

I am working on a free software project: https://github.com/ccr/ccr

In this project I am building some shared-object libraries which are actually plugins for HDF5.

I don't want to install these libraries in /usr/local/lib. I want to install them in a special HDF5 plugin directory.

Here's what I have now:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(HDF5_ROOT)/include -I$(BZ2_ROOT)/include
plugindir = /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin

# The libh5bz2 library for plugin module.
# Build it as shared library.
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libh5bz2.la
libh5bz2_la_SOURCES = H5Zbzip2.c

LDFLAGS = -L$(BZ2_ROOT)/lib
```

How do I get my library installed in plugindir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the prefix (`lib_`) determines the installation path (`$libdir`).
You can setup your own prefix:

```
plugindir = ${prefix}/hdf5/lib/plugin
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = libh5bz2.la
```

sidenote: don't hardcode the full path in your Makefile. instead use the predefined variables. e.g. instead of <del>`/usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin`</del> use something like `${prefix}/hdf5/lib/plugin`, to allow users to easily change the actual installation path..

Comment: thanks for the downvote. in order to improve my future answers, it would be great if you could also leave a comment on **what* you think is wrong with my answer and *why* you downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable 'libdir' to a string which is a path.
The variable declares (to automake and libtool) where to install the library.
If not defined, the library installs to a conventional place.

```
# install into private dir "lib" near other plugin executables
libdir = $(plugindir)/lib
```

Aside: as you hardcoded the definition of plugindir, you might be installing to a weird place.
When you use ${prefix}
you might find it installs to a subdirectory of the conventional place:

```
plugindir = $(prefix)/hdf5/plugin/lib
```

then that might for example install to /usr/local/lib/hdf5/plugin/lib which is more conventional?

Also, you might need to set rpath on any executables or libraries that reference your library.